# Call div C function from Julia

Tags: c, julia

I am trying to familiarize with calling `C` functions from Julia.
I have some troubles with easy functions like `isalnum`.

Running

```
ccall( (:isalnum, "libc"), Bool, (ASCIIString,), "k")
```

Returns always false.

I also tried to use the function "div" which returns quotient and reminder of a division. To store both values I created a type

```
type Foo
         A::Int64
         B::Int64
end
```

and then run

```
t = ccall( (:div, "libc"), Foo, (Int64,Int64,), 7,3)
```

but the results are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Julia doesn't currently support returning structs from ccalls. There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/3466) implementing this that fell through the cracks during the 0.3 release cycle and didn't get merged. If this were supported (it will be soon on the master branch), you would use an *immutable* structure to make it work. Like this:

```
julia> immutable Cdiv_t
           q::Cint
           r::Cint
       end

julia> ccall(:div, Cdiv_t, (Cint,Cint), 7, 3)
Cdiv_t(2,2)
```

As you can see, this is broken because the remainder part of the `Cdiv_t` structure is incorrect (it will currently always be the same as the quotient part). It's necessary to use an immutable structure because a mutable structure needs to store its components on the heap as individually allocated values – which is not compatible with C struct layout. Since `Cdiv_t` is immutable, its components can be stored inline, which is how C does it.

Also note the use of `Cint` as the Julia-side mirror of the C `int` type. This is always defined so that it is the correct type corresponding to C's `int` type – which is not always so easy to determine. The chapter on calling C and Fortran contains [a full list](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#type-correspondences) of Julia types that correspond to C types. You generally want to use the middle column names in your Julia code since they will work anywhere, not just on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The C function **int isalnum(int c);** takes an int and returns an int.  You can pass a character to **ccall** and it will be automatically be converted to Int64 but the function **convert(::Type{Int64}, ::ASCIIString)** does not exist.

Also, C considers anything non-zero as true, as does Julia when converting from *Int* to *Bool*, but when the return type is defined as *Bool* instead of *Int64* it does not work.

```
julia> ccall((:isalnum,"libc"),Int64,(Int64,),'k') 
8
```

You can pass non integers in as arguments because convert is implicitly called, but it's important to define the right return type.

```
julia> convert(Bool,ccall((:isalnum,"libc"),Int64,(Int64,),'k'))
true
```

and by comparison

```
julia> convert(Bool,ccall((:isalnum,"libc"),Int64,(Int64,),' '))
false
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear.
I still have to figure out what's going wrong with the div function though.